# HTML JS difference of dates with datapicker

Tags: javascript, html, input, datapicker

I added the script to the datapicker

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
});
});
</script>
```

and the script for the difference of dates

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function startEndDate() {
    from= document.modpren.from.value; //prima data la prende vuota
    to= document.modpren.to.value; //seconda data

    var fromArray = from.split('/');
    fromdate = new Date(fromArray[2], fromArray[1]-1, fromArray[0]);

    var toArray = to.split('/');
    todate = new Date(toArray[2], toArray[1]-1, toArray[0]);


   alert ((todate-fromdate)/86400000);
    }
    </script>
```

the problem is that in the "giorni" does not write the days that there are between the two dates.

```
 <input type="number" name="giorni" id="giorni" value=""  >
```

can someone help me?
I looked in the other post but I have not found solution
thanks so much

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `callback_field: '#giorni';`

Comment: test :) this is a test.... callback_field: '#giorni';
focusElements: '#giorni';

/*alert ((todate-fromdate)/86400000);*/
document.modpren.giorni.value = (todate-fromdate)/86400000

Comment: you can see the example is not working at the following url http://www.motoeshopping.com/prenotazionenew.html

Answer (score 0):

The date format you have specified while creating the datepicker is 'dd-mm-yy' and so the seperator is '-'
However, while splitting the string date, you are using '/' as the seperator and so you are not getting the desired output.

Make sure both seperators are same and it will solve the issue